# Using Pandas, how do I split based on the first space.

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

So i have a column of codes: "dataset.csv"

```
0020-004241 purple
00532 - Blue
00121 - Yellow
055 - Greem
0025-097 - Orange
```

Desired Output:

```
code              name_of_code
    0020-004241         purple 
    00532               blue
```

I want the codes and the words for the codes to be split into two different columns.

I tried:

`df =pandas.read_csv(dataset.txt)`

```
df = pandas.concat([df, df.columnname.str.split('/s', expand=True)], 1)
df = pandas.concat([df, df.columnname.str.split('-', expand=True)], 1)
```

`
It gave the unexpected output of: 
    purple none
    blue none 
    yellow none 
    green none 
    orange none

How should I split this data correctly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using `str.split(" ", n=1)`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename,names=['code'])
df[['code','name_of_code']] = df["code"].str.split(" ", n=1, expand=True)
df["name_of_code"] = df["name_of_code"].str.strip("-")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          code name_of_code
0  0020-004241       purple
1        00532         Blue
2        00121       Yellow
3          055        Greem
4     0025-097       Orange
```

---

Note that before version 2.0.0 of Pandas `str.split(" ", 1)` worked as well, but this has been deprecated in 2.0.0 and now `str.split(" ", n=1)` must be used instead.

Comment: Thank you! @Rakesh  Just wondering why is "df = pd.read_csv(filename,names=['code'])" the portion names = ['code'] necessary?

Comment: This will leave whitespace in `df['name_of_code']`. I think you need an additional `str.strip`.

Comment: What about importing the file with regex separators? `pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+\-*\s*')` (see the complete answer below)

Comment: Im getting the following error
`ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match`

Answer (score 2):

You can process this via a couple of split calls:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['0020-004241 purple', '00532 - Blue',
                           '00121 - Yellow', '055 - Greem',
                           '0025-097 - Orange']})

df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['col'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split().str[-1]

print(df)

                  col         col1    col2
0  0020-004241 purple  0020-004241  purple
1        00532 - Blue        00532    Blue
2      00121 - Yellow        00121  Yellow
3         055 - Greem          055   Greem
4   0025-097 - Orange     0025-097  Orange
```

Answer (score 2):

**Two lines of code using lambdas**:

```
df['code'] = df['code_and_name_of_code'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ", 1)[0])
df['name_of_code'] = df['code_and_name_of_code'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ", 1)[1].replace('-',''))
```

**Inputs**:

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('data.txt')

    code_and_name_of_code
0   0020-004241 purple
1   00532 - Blue
2   00121 - Yellow
3   055 - Greem
4   0025-097 - Orange
```

**Apply Lambdas**

```
df['code'] = df['code_and_name_of_code'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ", 1)[0])
df['name_of_code'] = df['code_and_name_of_code'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ", 1)[1].replace('-',''))
```

**Note**:

- x.split(" ", 1) implies splitting on the first space
- x.split(" ", 1) is returned as a list where [0] exposes whatever is before the first space and [1] exposes whatever is after the first space

**Outputs**

```
    code_and_name_of_code   code         name_of_code
0   0020-004241 purple      0020-004241  purple
1   00532 - Blue            00532        Blue
2   00121 - Yellow          00121        Yellow
3   055 - Greem             055          Greem
4   0025-097 - Orange       0025-097     Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex as a separator when loading CSV to avoid further splittings.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

file = StringIO(
    """0020-004241 purple
    00532 - Blue
    00121 - Yellow
    055 - Greem
    0025-097 - Orange"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+\-*\s*', header=None)
```

Of course, you may add the headers, but I'm trying to stay close to your initial input with this example.

Now `read_csv` produces the following DF:

```
             0       1
0  0020-004241  purple
1        00532    Blue
2        00121  Yellow
3          055   Greem
4     0025-097  Orange
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.str.extract` with a regular expression.

```
df[['code', 'name_of_code']] = df.col.str.extract('(.*\d+)\s-?\s?(.*)', expand=True)

print(df)
                  col         code name_of_code
0  0020-004241 purple  0020-004241       purple
1        00532 - Blue        00532         Blue
2      00121 - Yellow        00121       Yellow
3         055 - Greem          055        Greem
4   0025-097 - Orange     0025-097       Orange
```